# Сканирование папок с музыкой

Tags: android

Есть метод, который сканирует все папки с музыкой и добавляет в массив List. Проблема его в том, что он добавляет каждую папку столько раз сколько в ней песен. Как можно сделать, что бы при нахождении первой песни, он добавлял папку в список, а сам переходил к следующей папке?

```
public ArrayList<ModelFolder> scanFolders(File dir){
    String d;
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file:files){

        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            scanFolders(file); }
        else
        {
        if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {

            int i = dir.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
            d= dir.toString().substring(i+1);


                data.add(new ModelFolder(d,"",dir.toString(),""));


        }
        }
    }
    return data;
```

Comment: Ну - решение в лоб. Получив текущюю папку сравнивайте ее с  уже добавленными ранее папками и если такая уже есть - не добавляйте ее снова

Comment: Можно так, но если в папке 3000 песен, зачем её 2999 раз сканировать в пустую? Хотелось бы оптимальнее.

Comment: так может оператором continue воспользуетесь?

Comment: Как?...........

Comment: после data.add(new ModelFolder(d,"",dir.toString(),"")); вставить  continue;

Comment: Так и делал, не помогает